# Connect to AWS EC2 instance with Ansible

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible

I am learning ansible.
How do I connect with aws EC2 machine with ansible? I created this machine with Cloudformation . Can I do something like (the ip is stored in bash as an environment variable my_db )

```
- name: Test 
  hosts: "{{ lookup('env','my_db') }}"
  user: ec2-user
  vars_files:
    - vars/test.yml
  tasks:
    - name: install tarball
```

(and do stuff here on machine)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with cloudformation except that the instance was created using CF, correct? Is the instance tagged?

Comment: Yes that is right, sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with a sample script to see if it works.

To answer your question: **yes, you can do it** if you set the environment variable `my_db` to the instance IP. But the recommended way is to pass the IP or use EC2 dynamic inventory script and instance name so that you can use the same playbook for multiple hosts.

```
- name: Test 
  hosts: "{{ my_host }}"
```

You can pass the IP as command line argument

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "my_host=<my_db_ip>" my_playbook.yml
```

or pass hostname (tag:Name)

```
ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/ec2.py --extra-vars "my_host=tag_Name_HOST_NAME" my_playbook.yml
```

Comment: So   hosts: "{{ my_host }}" - should I use   hosts: "{{ my_db }}" in my case? And thanks !

Comment: Use the same value you specified in `--extra-vars`

Comment: Do I need to call it with --extra-vars ? If i want to skip extra-vars can I just set { { my_db }} and will it look up ? If not, then will {{ lookup('env','my_db') }}" work ?

Comment: If you are not using `--extra-vars`, you have to use `{{ lookup('env','my_db') }}` (your original code)